# IIS header hosts through a DMZ

Tags: iis, iis-7, reverse-proxy

I have an IIS 7 publicly facing site.

mydomain.com

i would like to have the sites.

```
app1.mydomain.com => internalserver/app1
app2.mydomain.com => internalserver/app2
```

I currently have Application Request Routing set up to do this. and it is working fine.

```
mydomain.com/app1 => internalserver/app1
mydomain.com/app2 => internalserver/app2
```

I believe i need to adjust the header hosts or something like that but am not sure how that will affect the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

[Nearly the same question was asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550505/url-rewriting-with-iis-6-7-rewriting-host-name-httphost).  Essentially, the answer was to use [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) instead to accomplish the goal.

Comment: We use ISAPI_Rewrite and it's brillaint - worth every cent.

Comment: IIS7 has a heap of rewrite functions.  is there something specific about ISAPI_Rewrite that it is missing to accomplish this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a lot of experience with the URL rewrite functions of IIS7, so I don't have a built-in solution.  Everything that I've read points to using an external tool when you need to rewrite based on the domain name and not the URL path.